# Grid.draw to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, gridview, ggplot2

I have a loop that creates several GGPlot charts, and then uses grid.draw to remove some of the clipping so some of my data labels can show correctly.

However, when it comes time to export all of these to PDF, I only get the final chart.

To give you a sense, here is my code:

```
require(scales)
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)


pdf("test.pdf", paper="USr", height=8, width=10)  
for (i in meps_seq) { 


  list=levels(df.long$locale)[eval(parse(text=i))]

  p=ggplot(....long command...)

  gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p)) 

  gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off" 

  grid.draw(gt)
      }
dev.off()
```

Unfortunately I only get one page on the PDF when I should have 5 or so. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `grid.newpage()`

Comment: Works. thanks. It should be an accepted answer.